# Filtering posts in listify (WP theme) in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a WP theme called [Listify](https://astoundify.com/products/listify/) and a plugin, [WP Job Manager](https://wpjobmanager.com/), to create a super quick MVP for my business. I've never done PHP but I need to make really quick changes, and I wasn't able to solve my problem after a lot of googling :(

**Target:** I'm trying to do an inverse filter where the user gives 2 dates, `$start_date` and `$end_date`. The function needs to return an array of job listings' `id`s that have their own `$start_date` and `$end_date`s **outside** of the user's given dates. (This is the whole if condition part).

**Problems:** 1) I can't get the IDs of the job listings and 2) I can't access the `end_date` and `start_date` of each job listing, that I custom added.

Of course, because I custom added the `end_date` and `start_date`, I know that the fields are called `start_date` and they belong to each listing. But how do I access it? Assuming that a `job_listing` is an object like in java, how do I access its field? Is my accessing (`$listing->get_object()->start_date`) wrong? Below is my full code.

```
function get_listings_outside_date( $start_date, $end_date ) {
    $post_ids = array();

        foreach(get_job_listings() as $listing) {
             if( ($listing->get_object()->start_date < $start_date || 
               $listing->get_object()->start_date > $end_date) && ($listing-
               >get_object()->end_date < $start_date || $listing-
               >get_object()->end_date > $end_date  ) {
                  $post_ids[] = $listing;
               }
        }
        return $post_ids;
}
add_filter( 'facetwp_facet_filter_posts', function( $return, $params ){
    $selected_values = $params['selected_values'];
    if ( 'availability' == $params['facet']['name'] ) {
        $start_date = $selected_values[0];
        $end_date = $selected_values[1];

        // get post IDs of available listings outside these dates
        $post_ids = get_listings_outside_date( $start_date, $end_date 
        );
        return $post_ids;
    }
    return $return;
}, 10, 2 );
```

I looked at the documentations and the function.php files for the theme/plugin, but I couldn't find any of the basic function declarations. Since it's a popular plugin, I'm asking here, but please do point me in any direction. Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer all of this, but you will likely want to look into the get_post_meta() function for your custom fields within the foreach loop. Something along the lines of get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'start_date', true).